# bash for loop work in command line, but failed in script

Tags: bash, for-loop, debian

When a run a for statement in debian bash command line, it works fine.
But when I run it in a sh script or run it with bash command, it's keeping report "error near unexpected token `do'"
Where is the difference?

```
[leon@www] ~/tmp $ for i in {1..10}; do echo $i; done
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
[leon@www] ~/tmp $ bash for i in {1..10}; do echo $i; done
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
```

BTW, all works fine in centos enviorment.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `-c` option so that bash reads the commands from the string you pass in. Also, use single quotes around the command.

```
bash -c 'for i in {1..10}; do echo $i; done'
```

Answer (score 4):

your bash command line ends with the first ;

so it gets executed separately as:

```
bash for i in {1..10};
do echo $i;
done
```

and man bash says command argument should be a file to load: bash [options] [file]

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap all your script inside inverted commas or in a file. Because here, you're doing `bash for i in {1..10}` then `do echo $i` and so on. You should use -c option if you don't put it in a file.